# How to use Math.pow for calculating bmi

Tags: java, math

I am trying to write a program that calculates the BMI of men or women. My problem at the moment is as I have declared all variables and imported `java.util.scanner`.
I just can't get the codes to run the formula I've used for calculating and determining if the person is male or female. You can find my code below.
P/S yes some of the messages are in french I am studying CS in french at the moment but it shouldn't be a problem. Thank you in advance for those who could help me.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class exercise11 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          //Decleration des variables
          double Poids;
          double Taille;
          double sc;
          double MetH;
          double MetF;
          Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

          System.out.println("Mettrez votre Poids");
           Poids = in.nextDouble();

          System.out.println("Mettrez votre Taille");
           Taille = in.nextDouble();


          Scanner Gender = new Scanner(System.in);
          System.out.println("Mettre votre sexe");

          String gender = "Homme";
          String gender2 = "Femme";
          gender = Gender.next();
          gender2 = Gender.next();
          sc = Math.pow(Poids, 0.425) * Math.pow(Taille, 0.725) *0.202;
          MetH = sc * 24 * 40;
          MetF = sc * 24 * 35;

          System.out.println("Le Metabolisme pour un homme est: " + MetH);
          System.out.println("Le Metabolisme pour une femme est: " + MetF);
    }

}
```

I expected the codes to use the formula and return the value but there is nothing after I declared my height weight and sex.

Comment: Side Note:- you initialize scanner 2 times.

Comment: code seems fine to me. what error or exception are you facing ?

Comment: do you need both gender?

Comment: @GhostCat sorry about that I am still quite new on the site I will take up your advice to make my question easier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working fine. It seems that you are not providing correct number of inputs.

I tested code with following inputs:

```
12 23 Homme
```

Following is your code after some code refactoring. You can [see it working here](https://ideone.com/ivugsL):

```
pulic class exercise11 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try(Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in))
        {
          System.out.println("Mettrez votre Poids");
          double Poids = in.nextDouble();

          System.out.println("Mettrez votre Taille");
          double Taille = in.nextDouble();

          System.out.println("Mettre votre sexe");
          String gender = in.next();

          double sc = Math.pow(Poids, 0.425) * Math.pow(Taille, 0.725) *0.202;
          if( gender.equalsIgnoreCase("Homme") )
          {
            double MetH = sc * 24 * 40;
            System.out.println("Le Metabolisme pour un homme est: " + MetH);
          }
          else if( gender.equalsIgnoreCase("Femme") )
          {
            double MetF = sc * 24 * 35;
            System.out.println("Le Metabolisme pour une femme est: " + MetF);
          }
          else
          {
            System.out.println("Vous avez entré un sexe invalide");
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much you're a life saver :)

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `Gender.next()` twice when taking input in for the Gender.  This is making it appear that the program is not doing anything because it is waiting for an extra input.

You should only use one variable for the gender and then use an `if` to check what the gender is and do the calculation accordingly.

Here is what it would look like corrected:

```
System.out.println("Mettre votre sexe (Homme or Femme)");
String gender = in.next();
sc = Math.pow(Poids, 0.425) * Math.pow(Taille, 0.725) *0.202;
MetH = sc * 24 * 40;
MetF = sc * 24 * 35;

if (gender.equalsIgnoreCase("Homme")) {
    System.out.println("Le Metabolisme pour un homme est: " + MetH);
}
else if (gender.equalsIgnoreCase("Femme")){
    System.out.println("Le Metabolisme pour une femme est: " +  MetF);
}
```

Now when a user types `Homme` or `Femme` it will do the correct calculation.  I also removed the extra `Scanner` you used called `Gender`, and just reused the `in` `Scanner`.

If you want to *always* calculate both genders, you do not need to take input for this at all!  Just immediately calculate both, and delete all the code you use to take in user input for gender.

**EDIT:**  Here is full code with the changes done:

```
class exercise11 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      //Decleration des variables
      double Poids;
      double Taille;
      double sc;
      double MetH;
      double MetF;
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Mettrez votre Poids");
       Poids = in.nextDouble();

      System.out.println("Mettrez votre Taille");
       Taille = in.nextDouble();

      System.out.println("Mettre votre sexe");
       String gender = in.next();

      sc = Math.pow(Poids, 0.425) * Math.pow(Taille, 0.725) *0.202;
      MetH = sc * 24 * 40;
      MetF = sc * 24 * 35;

      if (gender.equalsIgnoreCase("Homme")) {
          System.out.println("Le Metabolisme pour un homme est: " + MetH);
      }
      else if (gender.equalsIgnoreCase("Femme")){
          System.out.println("Le Metabolisme pour une femme est: " +  MetF);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks i'm trying it now but somehow the last line of code gave me a fault that said "Syntax error on token "MetF", delete this token. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @Quang Cao Check your brackets, the `{` and `}` and make sure they are placed correctly.  Could be the cause.  This entire code should be enclosed in the `main` and the `class`.  You still need the beginning of your code too, I just did not include that part.

Comment: I've tried what you have said and ut still display the same error.  if (gender.equalsIgnoreCase("Homme")) {
  System.out.println("Le Metabolisme pour un homme est: " + MetH);
  }
 else if (gender.equalsIgnoreCase("Femme")) {
  System.out.println("Le Metabolisme pour une femme est: " MetF);
 }                                                                                                                                        is what i wrote, maybe i have missed smt?

Comment: @Quang Cao I got it working on mine,  give me a bit I will post the entire code.

Comment: @Quang Cao Posted it as an edit, you should be able to copy and paste that entire block in and run it.